# Way to allow users to delete textbox content but not edit it?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

On my form I have a control that displays a generated ID number. I want to allow the user to delete this number (necessary to generate a new ID number), but not be able to edit it or create their own.

So far I can think of three workarounds, none ideal, and I was wondering whether anyone had a handier solution? Most of my problems come with balancing between making it easy to use the form but difficult to accidentally/carelessly delete the ID number.

Workaround #1: Keep the control disabled at all times, add a button to allow them to clear it. Downside: I already have several buttons in that area on the form and it's getting a little crowded, so I'd like to avoid that.

Workaround #2: Convert the textbox into a combobox with no options listed and edits set to no, so they can delete the information but not add any. Downside: Dropdown arrow on the control may confuse users into thinking they should actually use a combobox, would need to give them an explanatory popup message if they try to enter data and they're already encountering a lot of messages if they try to do forbidden actions/to confirm deletion of records/certain important controls.

Workaround #3: Allow them to generate a new ID number while they already have an ID number, resetting it. Downside: Again, would have to give them message interactions to confirm that they want to delete the ID number, seems a little messier than making them delete it to confirm they don't want an ID number. Worried about bordering on message fatigue meaning users wouldn't bother reading that they are deleting an existing number.

If I can't find a better workaround, I'll probably go with Workaround #2, as it seems like the least work for me. Anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: Is "empty ID" an acceptable state in a saved record? If no: #3, if yes: #1. I would find #2 very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the BeforeUpdate event of the textbox:

```
 Cancel = Not IsNull(Me!SerialNumber.Value)
 If Cancel = True Then
      MsgBox "Number can be deleted but not edited."
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I added `Me.SerialNumber.Undo` after the message so users weren't (to them) stuck in an interaction where they had a new nonsense value and couldn't figure out how to undo it.